# Update table to record position based on text column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
id | position | name
1  |  2       | a
1  |  3       | b
1  |  1       | c
-------
2  |  1       | a
2  |  3       | b
2  |  4       | c
2  |  2       | d
--------
3  |  2       | a
3  |  1       | b
```

How can I write an `UPDATE` statement (NOT `SELECT`) to get a table like this?

```
id | position | name
1  |  1       | a
1  |  2       | b
1  |  3       | c
-------
2  |  1       | a
2  |  2       | b
2  |  3       | c
2  |  4       | d
--------
3  |  1       | a
3  |  2       | b
```

The position will always start by 1.

Currently my code is

```
ORDER BY id, name
```

So it is arranged by id first and then name. I want to change the wrong position numbers.

Comment: Sorry, was updating question wanted to simply it for the users but realized removing one column makes a ton of difference :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the table so that the position column corresponds to the position of the 'name' column (in this example, the alphabet), you can use a case statement:

```
UPDATE myTable SET position =
   CASE
      WHEN name = 'a' THEN 1
      WHEN name = 'b' THEN 2
      WHEN name = 'c' THEN 3
      ...
      ELSE 26
   END;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc2c2/1) example.

---

**EDIT**

To order based on the strings you have, you can first write a query using a variable to get the position of each string like this:

```
SET @position := 0;

SELECT @position := @position + 1, name
FROM(
  SELECT DISTINCT name
  FROM myTable
  ORDER BY name) t;
```

Once you have that temporary table, you can join it to your original table and update `position` of the original to match `position` of the temp table, like this:

```
SET @position := 0;

UPDATE myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT @position := @position + 1 AS position, name
  FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM myTable
    ORDER BY name) t) tmp ON tmp.name = m.name
SET m.position = tmp.position;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3118f/1) example of that.

Comment: But that was just an example in reality it is some huge string which are just ordered in ascending order.

Comment: @Indigo I have edited my answer to show an alternative.

Comment: Sweet! Ill try it out and let you know! +1 for now since your fiddle works!! :D

Comment: For 'SET @position := 0;'  it says must declare variable 'pos'

Comment: Sounds like it might be a typo, but if you're using a Stored Procedure you might need to [check this out](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/variables-in-stored-procedures.aspx).

Comment: CREATE TABLE myTable (pos int, ids int , name varchar(max));
SET @pos := 0;

Comment: two lines of relevant code but ill check what you gave out )

Comment: @Indigo what is varchar(max) ?? Is that valid syntax?

Comment: Yeah! i read it online! apparently if you have a really long varchar put that! is it bad?

Comment: I've just never seen it before, and I wonder if it's a problem. It's probably not, but if you want to be sure you can try using `VARCHAR(100)` (or something large) and see if the error persists.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does :( I put 500!

Comment: When you copy your sql into SQL Fiddle does it fail too? If it does, can you  link that so I can see it?

Comment: Your fiddle works great! However, my actual SQL query is a bit more complex. Not sure if you will understand my SQL query without background knowledge. No worries, great work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80705/discussion-between-mcadam331-and-indigo).